# Error debugging application when running visual studio code server

Tags: visual-studio-code, coder

I'm running VS Code Server in a docker container via [CapRover](https://caprover.com/) (which uses code server package from [Coder](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest)). For editing code it works great, but when I debug the app (I tried Astro and Svelte), the index page loads, but all other links are broken. The index loads with a URL that looks like this: https://vscode.mydomain.com/proxy/3000/ so links URL's like https://vscode.mydomain.com/blog give a 404. If I manually enter https://vscode.mydomain.com/proxy/3000/blog, the page loads. Is there a way to configure Code to not include the /proxy/3000?

Comment: what? so it only works when you add `proxy/3000`, but you're asking how to make VS Code _not_ include that?

Comment: When I run the dev server to test the application I want to be able to test from `https://vscode.mydomain.com/blog` instead of `https://vscode.mydomain.com/proxy/3000/blog`.